# jQuery stop fadeTo effect

Tags: jquery

what I want is a sort of a mouse-trail effect, when you hover up or down the divs. But if you hover the mouse too fast a few times and then stop, the effect keeps repeating on it's own.

How can I solve this? I think I need some kind of a de-queue thing like with animate option, but for the fadeTo function. any ideas?

```js
$(".test").mouseover(function(e) {
  $(this).fadeTo(200, 1);
}).mouseout(function(e) {
  $(this).fadeTo(200, 0.3);
});
```

```css
.test {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #000000;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='test'>asd</div>
<div class='test'>asd</div>
<div class='test'>asd</div>
<div class='test'>asd</div>
<div class='test'>asd</div>
<div class='test'>asd</div>
<div class='test'>asd</div>
<div class='test'>asd</div>
<div class='test'>asd</div>
```

Comment: Maybe: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stop an effect in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59896/how-do-i-stop-an-effect-in-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `.stop` method to stop previous animations. If you pass in `true` as an argument, it will also clear queued animations.

If I've understood what you're looking for correctly, then what you want is this (you said you want a "mouse trail", which I'm taking to mean you don't want the previous animation to stop as soon as the mouse leaves that element, hence only the one call to `.stop`):

```
$(".test").mouseover(function(e){
    $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(200,1);
}).mouseout(function(e){
    $(this).fadeTo(200,0.3);
});
```

You can see that running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sJFLq/4/).

Answer (score 4):

Exactly as you described it in your title:)

```
$(".test").mouseover(function(e){
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(200,1);
}).mouseout(function(e){
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(200,0.3);
});
```

Comment: simply stopping also reduces the smooth trail effect.

Comment: @aoi I think James Allardice's answer is exactly what you want!

Answer (score 2):

Add `.stop()` for terminating you previous animation: http://jsfiddle.net/sJFLq/5/

```
$(".test").mouseover(function(e){
    $(this).stop(true, true).fadeTo(200,1);
}).mouseout(function(e){
    $(this).stop(true, true).fadeTo(200,0.3);
});
```

Comment: Make sure and set the two parameters to stop as desired.  The first parameter clears the queue of any other pending animations for this object and the second one jumps to the end of the animation (often required to position the next animation properly).  Usually, you want `.stop(true, true)`.  The default for both is false.  See http://api.jquery.com/stop/ for more info.