# jQuery stop fadeTo()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to stop a fadeTo() animation. I have a block of 4 pictures where 3 of them (the unhovered) should turn dark and the hovered stays at an opacity of 1. Unfortunately, the code I have so far makes every, including the hovered one turn dark before this one "lights up" again. Instead, I just want it to stay at 100% in first instance because everything else makes the website appear unresponsive.

What I have so far is:

```
$("#submenu").load("submenu.html", function(){
    function darken(){; 
    $("#submenu li").find("img").fadeTo( 100, 0.20  );
    }   

    function brighten(){
$("#submenu li").find("img").fadeTo( 100, 1.00  );
    }   

    $('#submenu li').each(function(index) {

            $(this).hover(
                  function () {
                    darken();

            //       $(this).stop(1,0).fadeTo(100, 0.20);
// if I do this ^ this image stays dark, even when hovered, and stays black when unhovered

           //        $(this).stop(1,0).fadeTo(100, 0.20);
// this ^ has no effect on the image whatsoever and it stays dark if I remove the line below

                $(this).find("img").fadeTo( 100, 1.00  );
// keeping this ^ line, it shows the behavior as stated in the question
                  }, 
                  function () {
                    brighten ();  
                  }
            );


    });
```

I messed around a lot with the (true, false) statements in the stop() call, but haven't had any success with any combination so far.

Comment: Can you add Jsfiddle link?

Comment: currently the fading is not showing on fiddle, just need to capsulate the code a bit, pls wait

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery stop fadeTo effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496564/jquery-stop-fadeto-effect)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I still know nothing about web dev (I am an app dev) but what I now did is passing the element to the darken() method so it knows what "not to" darken. Will post code later when it's cleaned up.

```
$("#submenu").load("submenu.html", function(){

    function darken(topkek){

        $.each($('#submenu ul li'), function( index, value ) {
            if(topkek.innerHTML!=$(this).html()){
                $(this).find("img").stop(true).fadeTo( 100, 0.40  );
            }
// I think one couldn't have done this worse than here but if it look stupid and it work, it ain't stupid
        }); 
    }   


    function brighten(){
        $("#submenu li").find("img").stop(true).fadeTo( 450, 1.00  );
    }   

    $('#submenu li').each(function(index) {

            $(this).hover(
                  function () {
                    darken(this);                   
                  }, 
                  function () {
                    brighten ();  
                  }
            );


    });

    });
```